# Error when using #include " " directive in codeblocks

Tags: c, struct, include, header-files, declaration

I am very new to programming so this might be a stupid question.

I'm trying to put my struct in a separate header file but when I do so, I get this error:

> main.c|3|error: expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'int'
>   === Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===

This is the code from *main.c*:

```
#include "struct.h"

int main(void){

    return 0;
}
```

And this is *struct.h*:

```
struct test{

    int a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `;` after your struct:

It should be

```
struct test {
    int a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is **not** in your `#include` statement, rather in the *struct.h* file itself.

You forgot to add a `;` after the `struct` declaration.

To refer, the `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.2.1, *Structure and union specifiers*, the syntax of a `struct` declaration is

> *struct-declaration:*
>   *specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-list*<sub>opt</sub> ;

Note the `;` there at the end.

Accordingly, your structure declaration should look like

```
struct test {
int a;
};  // note the ; here
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, as noted in other answers, you are missing a semicolon after the `struct` declaration.

What however might not be terribly clear that when the compiler sees

```
#include "file.h"
```

it replaces that line (up to an including the newline) with the contents of `file.h` without much checking beyond the ability to preprocess it. In particular `file.h` does not have to be compilable on its own. So this:

file1.h:

```
struct test{

int a;
```

file2.h:

```
};
```

and this in file.c

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main() { /* etc */ }
```

would be perfectly legal (although it looks more like an entry for an obfuscated code contest).

In fact, the standard (up to C++11 anyway) indicates that if an include file doesn't end in a newline, then the effects are undefined, and the compiler might (or might not) join the last line of the include file with the next line of the source, which can lead to all sorts of fun.

The long and short of this - if you get a surprising error in your source code immediately after a `#include`, check the end of your `#include` file for errors, because that's where the problem is likely to be.

Answer (score 0):

In the header file `struct.h`, end the structure with a semi-colon.

Your code should then run fine.

Explanation:-

Structures have the following syntax:-

```
struct <structure-name> {
.
.
elements
.
.
}; // must end with semi-colon
```

and it's objects are declared with the following syntax:-

```
struct <structure-name> <object-name>;
```

Hope that helps.